# Editing multiple buffers in vim: "((1) of 3)" in status line

Tags: vim, buffer

When I switch between buffers in vim with ":bn" and ":bp", my status line shows the following handy information:

```
"foo.txt" 43 lines --88%-- ((1) of 3)                      38,1          All
```

(I think it's "set showmode" that enables that.)
But that "(1)" is always literally "(1)" -- it doesn't change as I change buffers.  (The parens around the "1" are strange as well.)

Does anyone know how to fix that?

ADDED: It probably has to do with something nutty in my .vimrc, which is here:  http://yootles.com/outbox/.vimrc

---

Relatedly, here's a handy trick to make switching buffers really painless (entries in .vimrc):

```
"left/right arrows to switch buffers in normal mode
map <right> :bn<cr>
map <left> :bp<cr>
```

---

Keywords to improve searchability: vim, multiple buffers, switching between buffers, strange status line.  [Add others here if you were looking for answers to this question and didn't find this on your first attempt!]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason vim shows ((1) of 3) is because of the argument list.  When you started vim, you probably included 3 file names as arguments.  Because you used :bn/:bp to switch buffers instead of :n/:N to move through the argument list, you're still on argument 1.  Read :h arglist-position.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the looks of your statusline; for example, this is mine:

```
set laststatus=2    " all windows have statuslines
set statusline=%mb%n:%f%R%Y\ %l/%L,%c:%v
```

---

1st EDIT:

Try looking in the help for

```
:help arglist-position
:help shortmess
```

I never used these options, so I cannot give you a detailed explanation, but with a little reading you should get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Ah, thanks; I will try that.  I don't have my statusline set to anything now.  I guess this is more of a workaround than a fix though, right?  (Not that there's anything wrong with that, I'm just wondering if this is really a bug in vim or what.)

Comment: @dreeves - Yes, this is more of a workaround. The problem is that I cannot reproduce the (...). That is not the default behaviour. "showmode" you mentioned has nothing to do with it, it just shows the mode you're in (e.g. --INSERT--, --NORMAL--). Could you add your vimrc in your post to help analyze

Comment: Sure!  yootles.com/outbox/.vimrc  You're probably right that it's due to some craziness in my vimrc.

Answer (score 1):

In my case status line is ok, but title of the gvim looks like you said.

You can consider changing both **statusline** and **titlestring** to the same value as they use the same pattern options.

For selecting buffers in a convenient way you can use
minibufexpl.vim : Elegant buffer explorer - takes very little screen space
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=159

or
0scan : Tags based search for any things you might want to find(ctags, buffers,...).
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2507